# AppKit objects in Obj-C++ header files?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa

I'm happily using C++ objects in both, objective C++ (.mm) header and implementation files as well as call into Objective C(++) classes from my C++ implementation files, **but** every attempt to use Objective C classes in the **C++ header file** results in compiler errors.

Stuff like this class declaration fails to compile:

```
class CQuartzTextRenderer {

public:
                 CQuartzTextRenderer();
 virtual        ~CQuartzTextRenderer();
 virtual void    Render(CDrawingOptions &inDrwOpt);


private:

  NSFont*  CreateNSFontForFontName(string &fontName, int fontSize);
};
```

no matter what (AppKit/..) includes I've tried.
Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you get errors/warnings? That would certainly help in giving you an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have an Objective-C class inside a header file that is included by a `.cpp` simply because XCode will use the standard g++ compiler and treat the file as plain C++.

To fix these errors (and be allowed to use Objective-C classes in header files) you must **make sure that header file is included ONLY by `.mm` files**, not in any `.cpp`.

Just an addition: it may happen that you actually have a `foobar.h` coupled with `foobar.mm`. This is correct and allows you to have Objective-C in the header file but if that file is included somewhere else by a `.cpp` or by another `.h` which is included by a `.cpp` then you'll get compilation errors. Mind that every unit is compiled independently from others.

Comment: Uh, right - **anybody** including that file must be Obj-C++ as well.. Sort of makes sense!

Comment: I can ensure this principle because I'm actually porting a 25k LOC project from Objective-C to C++ so I had to solve identical issues. First I renamed all `.m` files to `.mm`. Now I'm slowly renaming them to `.cpp` as soon as they don't require any Objective-C anymore..

Comment: ..sort of going the other way round porting a decent size legacy Carbon C++ app to Cocoa & renaming every source single file in the project to `*.mm` starts to look damn tempting! ;-)

Comment: It's always a matter of includes, you can even cheat a little bit and move includes from .h file to relative .mm file so that you can clearly split roles. If you move a Obj-C++ header included from an .h to a .mm then the relative .h won't need to be treated as Obj-C++ and so on..